# Microsoft DHCP server giving "old" lease to clients switching networks

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

I have 2 Windows Server 2012 R2 DHCP servers running in active/active load-balancing on one of the networks. DHCP requests from the other networks are DHCP relayed by the router to these DHCP servers.

I am noticing that people who are connecting to our Guest network and then switching to our corporate network (2 separate subnets) are still getting their old lease (from the Guest network) when they join the second network. If I manually delete the lease from the DHCP server and they request a new lease, then they would get the correct IP settings handed to them. This doesn't happen on just these 2 networks but on all the networks that are served by the DHCP servers.

Have any of you had this problem? Is it a configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Is this a Cisco WLC network?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your broadcast domains may be overlapping. I would try sniffing the network to make sure this is not the case.